# Build Ivy reposotory. Different artifacts patterns for different artifacts types?

Tags: repository-pattern, ivy

I want to build local ivy repository with artifacts types jars, sources, javadocs.

I plan such structure of repo:

```
jars/mylib-1.0.jar
sources/mylib-source-1.9.jar
javadocs/mylib-javadoc-1.9.jar
```

I want use  next artifact pattern for javadocs and sources (with [type] in artifact name)

```
[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact]-[type]-[revision].[ext]
```

and next pattern for jars (without [type] in artifact name)

```
[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]
```

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question I'd need some further time to test it out. In the meantime have you tried something along the following lines?

```
[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[type])-[revision].[ext]
```

If the **type** attribute is not present it will not be used.